# Can't find Method getInstance() for iText7, even though it recognizes the class PdfWriter

Tags: java, swing, jframe, itext

I want to use the pdf library iText(7) for a university project. I need it to convert a JFrame or some other Swing component directly to a pdf document. I use Eclipse and import kernel, lay, pdfa and sl4j via the pom.xml of the Maven project. It seems like the library was downloaded successfully. Therefore I can import `PdfWriter` and also declare Variables of this type.

The problem is that I can't use the static method `getInstance` for the class `PdfWriter` which is obviously vital for using the library.
It would be nice if someone has an idea what I did wrong importing or what is missing. I'm also open to alternatives for converting Swing components to pdf if there are any.

Comment: do you call getInstance from a PdfWriter instance you just create, or from the class (PdfWriter.getInstance()) ?

Comment: from the class, like PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(someDocument, new FileOutputStream("test.pdf"));

Comment: #getInstance was removed from the API when moving to iText 7. Are you sure you don't have iText 5 in your dependencies somewhere?

Comment: so there is no getInstance in iText7? i just tried to use code examples, its possible they have been used for iText 5. Im pretty sure i doint use iText 5. I import version 7.1.5 via maven repository in eclipse

Comment: okay the code examples were meant for iText 5... Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use iText 5 client code, presumably from an example somewhere, on top of the iText 7 binaries. That will not work, because the API is different.

You have two options: either look for example code that uses iText 7, or try iText 5. As an iText Software employee, I would recommend that you try iText 7 because iText 5 is end-of-life and will not be maintained actively anymore.

For good measure: creating a writable `Document` in iText 7 goes like this:

```
Document doc = new Document(new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("/path/to/output.pdf")));
```

Comment: yeah thats right... I found code examples which were posted a year ago, i assumed they were still funtional, but they are obviously written for iText 5. Thanks for the advice!